# Polya - Szego question

Tags: calculus

The following problem can be found in Polya and Szego book - exercise 19.2 on page 51. Prove that the sum is $\gamma$.

$\frac{1}{1}\\
-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\\
-\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8}...\\$

And so on...
Does anyone know how to help with this?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H_k$ be the harmonic numbers  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

The requested sum can be written as the limit for $n \to \infty$ of
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n  \left(H_{(k-1)^2}-H_{k^2-1}+\frac{k^2-(k-1)^2}{k^2}\right)=
\sum_{k=1}^n  \left(H_{(k-1)^2}-H_{k^2}+\frac{2k}{k^2}\right).$$
Summing the telescoping series gives
$$S_n=-H_{n^2}+2H_n=-H_{n^2}+\ln(n^2)+ 2(H_n-\ln n) \to -\gamma+2\gamma=\gamma$$
as $n \to \infty$.